# Beamer - No table of contents at top

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, header-footer

Once a table of contents is created, by

```
\tableofcontents
```

it is shown in at the top of the presentation, like in the following picture:

[image]

Is it possible to prevent the contents from appearing at the top, but only at the one frame where `\tableofcontents` command is used at the beginning?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can clean up the headline by providing an empty template declaration: I am guessing that you are using `Warsaw` theme (since you did not provide any MWE)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
    \usetheme{Warsaw}
    \setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
    \title{Evolution and invasion}
    \author{Nadiah Kristensen}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \titlepage
    \end{frame}
    \frame{\tableofcontents}
    \section{Introduction}
    \section{Webworld}
    \section{Results}
    \subsection{As the web grows}
    \begin{frame}{As the web grows}{Generalizations}
        Frame 1 
    \end{frame}
    \subsection{it frightens me}
    \frame{2}
    \subsection{I like trains!}
    \frame{3}
    \section{Summary}
\end{document}
```

[image]